# Processing 32 bit integers on 32 bit hardware and on 64bit hardware, which is faster?

Tags: c, linux

I am programming C on linux, and which is faster in the following conditions?

1.processing 32bit integers on 32bit hardware and 64bit hardware

2.processing 64bit integers on 32bit hardware and 64bit hardware

Comment: Which hardware, what processing ?

Comment: in most 32 bits CPU, processing 64 bits values requires more code produced by the compiler, so it's a safe bet to say it will slower than in a 64 bits CPU ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should tell on what exact hardware, and what kind of processing.

And more importantly, you should benchmark your application, taking into account that *premature optimization is evil*.

Standard C99 provides you with the `<stdint.h>` with the `fastint_t` type (and others, e.G. `intptr_t`  or `int32_t`...); there is also a `<inttypes.h>` standard header.

I believe you should not bother at first. If you know that some integer data type is *very* crucial to your application, you might use your own typedef, eg.

```
typedef intfast_t myimportantint_t;
```

Then you develop your application using appropriately `myimportantint_t`, and benchmark it. You can then easily change that `typedef`. (So changing the size of your important integers would be easy, just changing that typedef and perhaps defining a `MYIMPORTANT_MAX` preprocessor constant, etc.).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694131/fastest-integer-type-for-common-architectures) very related to yours.

I believe you should not care that much.

Of course, 64 bits arithmetic on many 32 bits processors is more costly than 32 bits arithmetic.